# Play Console Pre-Launch Warning "Double splash screen"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-play-console, android-splashscreen

Doesn't matter what I do, Play Console always shows a warning on my pre-launch report:

*The crawler detected a blank loading screen or a custom splash screen that is shown in your app after the system splash screen. Users launching your app on Android 12 or higher will see 2 splash screens.
To fix this issue, update your app to use the SplashScreen API.*

I followed the instructions from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen and https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen but nothing works... The warning is always there.

I suspect this is a false positive. When I watch the innumerous videos that the pre-report gives me "showing" the issue, there's absolutely nothing wrong, no double splash screens nor anything...

Has anyone seen this? How to solve it?

Comment: Do you have any file/class that contains SplashScreen in name?

Comment: @KrzysztofS. No... I copied everything from the docs and even the theme name is Starting.

Comment: @KrzysztofS. I have met the same problem. And I have use Splash screen api. I have set theme and use this code. But play still shows doubl splash. I found my launch activity is named as SplashScreenActivity. is it releated? Does it work if I change this name?

Comment: @EricZhao yeah, for me it worked when I changed the name :)

Comment: @KrzysztofS. does it mean that if you even implement it as the docs say, you will still have that double screen warning if somewhere a name Splash is used?

Comment: @MarkDelphi yeah, I think so

Comment: @KrzysztofS. ok, I removed Splash from the theme name, but this didn't help.

Comment: @MarkDelphi then I was wrong, sorry :/

Comment: @KrzysztofS. no problem, we will get it, don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

"Double splash screen" warning on google play console is triggered when using splash screen API together with activity that have **only one view** (e.g. some kind of animation).

If you want to keep your animation screen (old splash screen) for any reason (like loading ads or else), just put another view on that activity, for example progress bar.

That will suppress Play console to mark that activity as splash screen and warning will gone away.

Comment: It's a compose app and it has only one view indeed I believe? I will try to play with that and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, compose app, with only one composable - lottie animation.

Comment: @Bruno any success so far? I am facing this issue, too. My app is also a compose app and it has only one MainActivity that hosts composable `setContent { .. } `. The Splash sscreen is done be Google Splash Screen API.

Comment: @Zoran is this "one view" thing documented somewhere?

Comment: @Mark I think not, but that solution worked for me., as soon as I added progress bar at bottom the warning disappeared.

Comment: @Mark Delphi, did you manage to resolve this issue any how? I also use compose in my app, don't use the splash screen apis, don't have a custom splash screen either, and I still get this warning.

Answer (score 1):

[React Native library states that it is not a problem.](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/issues/496#issuecomment-1862481987)

Answer (score 0):

***METHOD 1:***
Add to your style

```
<item name=”android:windowIsTranslucent”> true </item>
```

Example :

```
    <style name="RemoveAppSplashTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

Apply this theme to your app splash screen Activity.

```
 <activity
   android:name="com.app.SplashScreenActivity"
   android:theme="@style/RemoveAppSplashTheme"
   android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

============================================================

***METHOD 2:***

We can suspend the application to draw an existing splash screen and show the system splash screen until the application is ready. This will solve the app delay problem

```
private void setupOnPreDrawListenerToRootView() {
   View pView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
   pView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
               // Check if the initialization is done or not.
               if (isAppInitialized) {
                   // The content is ready, then start main activity.
                   pView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                   startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));  
                   return true;
               } else {
                   // The content is not ready, then suspend.
                   return false;
               }
           }
       });
}
```

☻♥ Done Keep Code.