Double splash screen To fix, update your app to use the SplashScreen API
I have warning in closed testing, i have implement splash screen API in my project, but play store always detected double splash screen in android 12 or higher.
Please help me to fix this problem

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainLayoutViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var keepSplashScreenOn = viewModel.isLoading.value

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.isLoading.collect {
                    keepSplashScreenOn = it
                }
            }
        }

        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            keepSplashScreenOn
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannelManager.apply {
                createNotificationChannelFCM(applicationContext)
                createNotificationChannelTest(applicationContext)
            }
        }

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            SmartcubeAppTheme {
                val startDestination by viewModel.startDestination.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                startDestination?.let {
                    Box(Modifier.safeDrawingPadding()) {
                        MainLayout(
                            initialScreen = it
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class MainLayoutViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenAppRepositoryImpl: ITokenAppRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _startDestination = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val startDestination: StateFlow<String?> = _startDestination
    val isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)


    init {
        getFlowToken()
    }

    private fun getFlowToken() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            tokenAppRepositoryImpl.getFlowAccessToken().collect {
                when (it) {
                    is SessionState.Loading -> Unit

                    is SessionState.Empty -> {
                        isLoading.value = false
                        _startDestination.value = Screen.Login.screenRoute
                    }

                    is SessionState.Exist -> {
                        isLoading.value = false
                        _startDestination.value = Screen.Dashboard.screenRoute
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


please correct my code, i got stuck in  here
playstore not detected double splash screen in android 12 or higher

It seems like this is sometimes reported as false positive, and no one knows how to actually resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098464/play-console-pre-launch-warning-double-splash-screen

so can i apply for production, and ignore this warning ?

You can check the migration guide to make sure you actually have added the SplashScreen API correctly: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate
Then, if you don't see any double splash screen while testing on devices, you might want to ignore the warning.
