React Native with Android Native: Splash Screen Closes Automatically Despite `setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }`
Description
To avoid Google Play's warning about double Splash Screen, I implemented the Android native Splash Screen API in my project react-native as described in the official documentation.
I utilized setKeepOnScreenCondition { true } to maintain the splash screen's visibility. Without this setting, the splash screen closes prematurely. Here is the relevant Kotlin code snippet from MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen: SplashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        splashScreen.apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
            setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenView ->
                // Placeholder for exit animation code
            }
        }

        // Handler to close the splash screen upon initialization completion
        lateinit var onInitLoadingFinishedHandler: () -> Unit

        onInitLoadingFinishedHandler = {
            splashScreen.apply { setKeepOnScreenCondition { false } }
            // InitLoadingManager is a singleton to manage the dispatch of loading states 
            InitLoadingManager.removeListener { onInitLoadingFinishedHandler() }
        }

        InitLoadingManager.addListener { onInitLoadingFinishedHandler() }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}

The issue occurs several seconds after the application starts, leading to a black screen that appears briefly immediately after the splash screen is initially displayed correctly. I have observed that the black screen coincides with the callback function of setOnExitAnimationListener being called. Although the exit animation starts during this black screen, it is not visible on the screen. It is only when onInitLoadingFinishedHandler() is executed that the remaining portion of the animation becomes visible.
Screenshot
Stage 1:
Splash Screen
Stage 2:
Black Screen
Stage 3:
Remaining exit animation
Other Codes

In styles.xml (v33)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">

        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/splashscreen_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/android_icon</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior">icon_preferred</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>

    </style>

</resources>


In AndroidManifest.xml

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
    <!-- others -->
</Application>

The splash screen should remain fully visible with its content rendered until explicitly dismissed by code, ensuring no black screen appears during the transition.

Try to pass null as argument in the onCreate function to check if the issue still persist.
or you can explore this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lottie-splash-screen
It support both image and video as splash. You can disable the splash after loading the app.

Thanks, but passing null to super.onCreate() can't solve the issue.
The package you proposed, can it avoid the double splash screen warning from Google Play console?

I have implemented splash screen using the above mentioned package it's working fine. I have my own custom video for splash screen. It accept json file format which you can get from the official site of https://lottiefiles.com/
You can review this question if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098464/play-console-pre-launch-warning-double-splash-screen
